# Span of a set of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

In Artin's Algebra book there is the following Lemma about vector spaces:

Let $S$ be an ordered set of vectors of $V$, and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. if $S\subset W$, then Span $S\subset W$.

Now, Artin presents this without proof and I'm not totally convinced it's correct. More specifically, I take issue with the proper subset statement. What if we take $S$ to be a basis for $W$? For instance, if we take the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, $S$ consists of just any nonzero vector, and $W$ is the subspace spanned by that vector. Then $S\subset W$ but Span $S = W$.

Is this a typo or am I committing some logical mistake somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, but Artin is using $"\subset"$ to mean a subset that may not be proper.  See the notation page in his text.